# Option to set a tag as default for first opening page

Tags: feature-request

When I log in, I usually search for one of the Favorite tag to click and view relevant questions.

Is there an option to set a default tag so that each time I log in, it automatically opens the page with questions of my relevant tag?

If this feature is not there, I want to add this request to your Suggestion Box.

Answer (score 5):

I usually just bookmark the tags:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Takes me straight to the PHP tag, it works for them all.

Comment: Good for people who can bookmark in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you'd want to do that, you'd miss out on a lot of things you didn't know you knew the answer too, I'd think. Besides, there are lots of alternatives:

### Favorites can be bookmarked or highlighted

The home page lists your favorite tags on the right:

[image: My favorite tags]

As you can see you can add new tags to that list with the textbox underneath it. Clicking on these will take you straight to their question overviews and each is just the base url `http://stackoverflow/questions/tagged/` plus the tag name. You could bookmark those for easy access.

Moreover, any question that matches your favorite tags are already highlighted on the home page:

[image: some highlighted questions]

### You can create your own homepage with all your favorite tags

A lesser known trick is that you can combine tags to show only questions that match any of those by using the `questions/tagged/` URL with the word `or` inserted between tags:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+jquery
```

and you can string all your tags together; now you are presented with the list of questions that match either the [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tags:

[image: number of questions matching either jquery or python]

and you could bookmark that one too. If you feel uncomfortable creating such a URL by hand, just enter your tags with the `[or]` tag in between in the search box and hit enter; e.g. `[python] [or] [jquery] [or] [mysql]`.

### You can filter questions on StackExchange.com

Last but not least, you could use the [Filtered Questions feature](https://stackexchange.com/filters/5794/favorite-tags) of stackexchange.com:

[image: Stack Exchange favorite questions]

Here you can filter questions from across all SE sites; here they are filtered on my favorite tags. The selected filter *sticks* so next time I visit that page it'll still show me my filter of choice. Bookmark that one and you get to see all relevant questions in one place!

Comment: One of my previous question states that Favorite Tags are not clearly visible because of Ads.

Comment: But that's a separate issue then, isn't it? You are clearly aware of the feature, in any case. :-)